# Proper way to reference a drawable resource while creating an object?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an object of a Person class I made. I am creating the first object just in the main activity. I have written the following code:

```
new Person[0] = (R.drawable.brule, "Steve Brule", 1234, "Danger Zone 123", 5811910,
                    "coolguy@hotmail.com", "skater", "drangus", true, true, "01/01/1992");
```

The comma following R.drawable.brule is giving a syntax error " ) is expected" and the ; at the end of the statement is saying " ; is expected". Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Here is my constructor:

```
public Person(int ImageID, String Name, int ID, String Address, int Phone, String Email, String Job,
              String SupName, boolean Role,  boolean Married, String Bday) {
    setmImageID(ImageID);
    setmName(Name);
    setmID(ID);
    setmAddress(Address);
    setmPhoneNumber(Phone);
    setmEmail(Email);
    setmJob(Job);
    setmSupName(SupName);
    setmRole(Role);
    setmMarried(Married);
    setmBday(Bday);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the constructor on this way:

```
Person[0] = new Person(R.drawable.brule, "Steve Brule", 1234, "Danger Zone 123", 5811910,
                    "coolguy@hotmail.com", "skater", "drangus", true, true, "01/01/1992");
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't been coding for a while so I guess I just forgot my syntax :\

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing the same thing. Just put a comma in curly braces and create another one it will expand its size accordingly.

```
Person person[] = {new Person(R.drawable.brule, "Steve Brule", 1234, "Danger Zone 123", 5811910,
                    "coolguy@hotmail.com", "skater", "drangus", true, true, "01/01/1992")};
```